# Sqlite recursive ORDER BY

Tags: sqlite, recursion, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "tester" (
    "id"    INTEGER UNIQUE,
    "pid"   INTEGER,
    "pos"   INTEGER,
    "nm"    VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

INSERT INTO 'tester' (id, pid, pos, nm)
VALUES (1,  0, 0, "My Tester"),
       (2, 1, 0, "cat1"),
       (4, 9, 1, "subcat1"),
       (9, 1, 1, "cat2"),
       (10, 2, 0, "subcat3"),
       (13, 2, 1, "subcat2"),
       (14, 9, 0, "subcat4"),
       (15, 4, 0, "data1"),
       (16, 4, 1, "data2"),
       (17, 13, 0, "data3"),
       (18, 13, 1, "data4"),
       (19, 10, 0, "data5"),
       (20, 10, 1, "data6"),
       (21, 14, 0, "data7"),
       (22, 14, 1, "data8");
```

This represents a tree like this:

[image: Tree Look Like This]

I want to run query to get all from "data1" till "data8" ordered by `pos`.

I have the ids of all nodes from "data1" till "data8" but they are not in order.

I tried :

```
SELECT * 
FROM "tester" 
WHERE id IN ("15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22") 
ORDER BY pos ASC
```

But the result is not as expected because the parent's positions are different.

The expected result is:

```
data5
data6
data3
data4
data7
data8
data1
data2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive common table expression to visit all records by following parent-child relationships. Use `order by` to make sure that a node's depth is given priority, or when nodes have the same depth, that `pos` defines the order of visiting them.

From the CTE you can then select what you need, filtering records by the desired `id` and selecting the names:

```
with recursive depth_first(id, pos, nm, level) as (

    select   id, pos, nm, 0
    from     "tester"
    where    pid = 0

    union all

    select   t.id, t.pos, t.nm, depth_first.level+1
    from     "tester" t
    join     depth_first 
          on t.pid = depth_first.id
    order by 4 desc, 2
)
select nm 
from   depth_first
where  id between 15 and 22;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time & effort trincot. I will test the code and will write back.

Comment: Hi, Just checked and result is as expected. Thanks. What i can not understand is order by 4 desc, 2.  What is 4 & 2 referring to?

Comment: They are column numbers in the `select` list, so it means sort by level descending, and then pos ascending. It is an alternative way to refer to the `select` list when you don't have a column name.

Comment: understand :) ..  Thanks again